# CASE WHEN not working in Spotfire

Tags: switch-statement, spotfire

I am having some trouble with a CASE WHEN argument well its probably more to do with the OVER function any help would be greatly appreciated. The error I am getting is 'The expression is not valid after OVER on line 2 character 51' 
The expression I have so far is

```
CASE  
WHEN [Pay in 2015] = 1 and [Reimburse in 2016]= 1 OVER ([Customer ID]))>=2 then 2
ELSE 0
END
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated 
[image]

[image]

Comment: You don't have a windowing function there, so you can't use an `over` clause. Could you explain what exactly you're trying to achieve? Some context will help us understand the question and ultimately have you.

Comment: @Mureinik: Thank you for the response I have attached a picture of what I am trying to achieve to to help explain. What I am trying to achieve is if there is a "1" in [pay in 2015] and a "1" in [Reimburse in 2016] and [Customer ID] remains the same then show me "2" in a new column esle "0" Thank you for the help

Comment: This helps, but still not sure I understand. How do you want the output to look? Just adding another column to this query, or something aggregate?

Comment: I have attached another pic I want another column to give me a "2" where the criteria matches so in the yellow "2"'s you can see that there is two "1" in column [pay in 2015] and there are two "1" in [Reimburse in 2016] and the [Customer ID] Remains the same. I hope his makes sense.

Comment: hi @PhilipConnell, it's great to share your data; a lot of people don't :) but it makes it much easier for us to test it if you can share it in text rather than an image. please check out the markdown help for info on formatting: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this... you may have to play with what you intersect for your specific data. It's hard to test without your data.

```
case 
   when 
     sum([Pay in 2015]) over (intersect([CustomerID],[Amount],[Date of Payment])) >= 2 
     and 
     sum([Reimburse in 2016]) over (intersect([CustomerID],[Amount],[Date of Payment])) >= 2 
   then 2 
   else 0 
end
```

**EDIT**

After looking at your data there I don't see a way to do this without a unique identifier for each charge and reimbursement. For example, in the data you pasted there are 4 charges. 2 for 80 and 2 for -80 meaning these would offset. However, what if there was another for 80 for the same Nature and Purpose? There isn't any expression that would be able to like the two credits to any two charges while ignoring the last one. Generally speaking you really need an ItemID or something that specifies a unique identifier for the charge and charge back. Otherwise, someone could credit an account with 80 bucks or 150 and there is no real way of telling what specific item that was for (what travel voucher, etc).

The best think you could do right now is look at the customer as a whole and return the total amount they were charged compared to the total amount they were credited, but reconciling each row isn't possible with guaranteed accuracy without the unique chargeID / coucherID / etc.

Sorry.

Comment: thank you for the help. Is there a way I could get a sample of my data on here? I have seen in other posts people have managed this.

Comment: The best way is to just copy and paste it (and select code format) so we can copy it to excel and test it. You can also use something like https://justpaste.it/ or another site where you can dump some data. Usually SO likes to keep it all in SO but it's not always the best option.

Comment: the just paste it link is https://justpaste.it/x7ot or the short version is https://jpst.it/M1aR  the excel formulas that got me the answers were Q: =N(AND(J2>0,YEAR(N2)=2015))
R: =N(AND(J2<0,YEAR(N2)=2016))
S: =SUMIFS(Q:Q,D:D,D:D,L:L,L:L)   +   SUMIFS(R:R,D:D,D:D,L:L,L:L)
T: =N(AND(SUMIFS(J:J,D:D,D:D,L:L,L:L,S:S,S:S)=0,S:S>=2))

Comment: Sorry got caught up today @PhilipConnell  I'll check tomorrow